# Output a number in PrettyFont

Tags: code-golf, ascii-art

I've designed a new font which I call PrettyFont. I've put much much time into perfecting it, but since I'm a working man I don't have time to finish it. Therefore it only contains 4 characters right now. One day when I've become rich it will become my life-long goal to finish it, but for now...

This is PrettyFont: (0, 1, 2, 3)

```
####  ##  #### ####
#  #   #  #  #    #
#  #   #    #   ###
#  #   #   #      #
####  ### #### ####
```

Each character is 4 pixels wide and 5 pixels high. Now! I want you to write me a program that outputs a number in PrettyFont so I can start sending designs to print.

**Rules:**

The input is a string number in base 4 (only characters 0-3), for example "01321". The program should be able to handle at least 10 characters in the string. BONUS points is given to the program that takes an actual base 10 integer instead of a string. *EDIT* clarification: the integer bonus means that one can enter any base 10 number, like 54321, and the program will convert it to base 4 and output it (in this case 31100301).

The output will be the number printed with PrettyFont. Example input and output:

```
> "321"
####
   #
 ###
   #
####

####
#  #
  # 
 #  
####

 ## 
  # 
  # 
  # 
 ###
```

Huge bonus to the program that can output it in a single row-fashion like this:

```
> "321"
#### ####  ## 
   # #  #   # 
 ###   #    # 
   #  #     # 
#### ####  ###
```

The '#' character is not a requirement, and can be replaced by any character.

In vertical output, an empty row is required between each PrettyFont character. If anyone makes the horizontal output, one white space character ' ' or a tab character is required between each PrettyFont character.

This is code golf, shortest code wins! (I need it short because my office computer has limited storage.)

Comment: It's not exactly a duplicate, but the only fundamental difference between this and http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/3628/flag-semaphore-encoder is the lookup table.

Comment: PrettierFont - `banner -c '#' 0123`

Comment: with 4 pixels wide you're gonna have issues with 'M'

Comment: How many chars is bonus for taking 10 base number as input?

Comment: I'm not really sure. I need to see some more solutions to get an idea of how hard it would be to do it. I'm not very good at code golf myself so... Suggestions appreciated!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

## k (<s>118 117 72 71 69</s> 66 chars)

<s>I haven't made much of an effort to golf this yet</s> but it achieves the desired horizontal output in not too many chars:

```
-1'" "/:'+(5 4#/:4 20#"# "@,/0b\:'0x066609ddd806db00e8e0)"I"$'0:0;
```

Takes input from stdin, prints output to stdout.

edit: By implementing a form of compression on the output "bitmap", I've reduced it to 72. The bitmap is now built by converting  64bit ints to binary and mapping the 0s and 1s to "#" or " ". <s>I could do it from hex like a few of the other solutions but I think this would end up longer</s>. Turns out hex is better.

Sample output for 012301:

```
####  ##  #### #### ####  ##
#  #   #  #  #    # #  #   #
#  #   #    #   ### #  #   #
#  #   #   #      # #  #   #
####  ### #### #### ####  ###
```

//edit: -6 char

Comment: Impressive. Shortest code yet! It might fit on my limited storage drive. Good job.

Comment: Down to 71. Given that the combined kdb+/q/k exe weighs in at a slim 392kB, this might be ideal for your limited storage drive ;)

Answer (score 10):

### Python3 (124)

```
s=input();[print(*["".join(" #"[0xf171ff429f72226f999f>>(20*int(x)+4*y+i)&1]for i in(3,2,1,0))for x in s])for y in range(5)]
```

Sorry, vertical was not interesting for me.

```
???/golf.py
1230012301203012030102301230
 ##  #### #### #### ####  ##  #### #### ####  ##  #### #### #### ####  ##  #### #### #### ####  ##  #### #### #### ####  ##  #### #### ####
  #  #  #    # #  # #  #   #  #  #    # #  #   #  #  # #  #    # #  #   #  #  # #  #    # #  #   #  #  # #  #    # #  #   #  #  #    # #  #
  #    #   ### #  # #  #   #    #   ### #  #   #    #  #  #  ### #  #   #    #  #  #  ### #  #   #  #  #   #   ### #  #   #    #   ### #  #
  #   #      # #  # #  #   #   #      # #  #   #   #   #  #    # #  #   #   #   #  #    # #  #   #  #  #  #      # #  #   #   #      # #  #
 ### #### #### #### ####  ### #### #### ####  ### #### #### #### ####  ### #### #### #### ####  ### #### #### #### ####  ### #### #### ####
```

Comment: Awesome one! Didn't expect so few characters for the horizontal one. Nice job.

Comment: Thx. I guess my idea (hex-number and shifts) should be even shorter in Ruby implementation.

Answer (score 10):

### J, <strike>84</strike> <strike>82</strike> <strike>81</strike> <strike>80</strike> <strike>75</strike> 69 characters

```
' #'{~(,4,.(4*".,' ',.1!:1[1)+/i.4){"1#:63231 37521 37415 37441 63487
```

Takes input from the keyboard:

```
   ' #'{~(,4,.(4*".,' ',.1!:1[1)+/i.4){"1#:63231 37521 37415 37441 63487 63487
0123210
 ####  ##  #### #### ####  ##  ####
 #  #   #  #  #    # #  #   #  #  #
 #  #   #    #   ###   #    #  #  #
 #  #   #   #      #  #     #  #  #
 ####  ### #### #### ####  ### ####
```

Magic numbers FTW (or for the second place in this case) :-)

Comment: Very nice... very nice... I'm impressed! Many good answers today. Maybe my designer-prints will turn out fine.

Comment: You could encode all  digits into one binary number and do a reshape on the result to get the corresponding number matrices.

Comment: @FUZxxl I did try to find the number for the full 80 bits, but `#:` didn't seem to work for that size of number. `#:1166416635908028473935870` and `#:1166416635908028473931775` both give the same answer for me.

Answer (score 8):

## C - <strike>164</strike> 151 characters horizontal

On IDEone: http://ideone.com/gljc3

The code (164 bytes):

```
i,j;main(){char n[99];gets(n);for(;j<5;++j){for(i=0;n[i];++i)printf("%.4s ","#####  # ##   #  ### #     #"+4*("01110233340135006460"[(n[i]-48)*5+j]-48));puts("");}}
```

[image]

## EDIT - 151 bytes

I added the suggestions from the comments and then some. It isn't exactly safe (0-length array that I `gets()` in to...) though.

```
char i,j=5,n[];main(){for(gets(n);j--;)for(i=puts("");n[i];printf("%.4s ","#####  # ##   #  ### #     #"+4*(0x1A600BA136E0248>>15*n[i++]-720+3*j&7)));}
```

Note, `i=puts("")` is undefined behavior since I'm treating `void` as `int`! It consistently returns `0` on my version of MinGW, but it returns `1` on the compiler IDEOne uses.

## Accepts decimal, outputs base 4 (167 bytes)

```
char i,j=5,n[];main(p){for(itoa(atoi(gets(n)),n,4);j--;)for(i=puts("");n[i];printf("%.4s ","#####  # ##   #  ### #     #"+4*(0x1A600BA136E0248>>15*n[i++]-720+3*j&7)));}
```

Comment: Ooh, a short one in C! That will surely run in under a minute on my old CPU. Good one.

Comment: Couldn't you save 3 chars by removing "!=0"?

Comment: Yea, thanks. I didn't catch that one.

Comment: Put `gets` within `for` (save 1). Move `puts` to the external `for`'s increment and save braces. Save paranthesis: `(n[i]-48)*5+j`->`n[i]*5-240+j`, same trick with `+4*(..`.

Comment: Okay down to 153 bytes. Not too bad for C I guess.

Comment: 151 bytes. I don't think it's going to get any better with the permitted built in types and rudimentary math functions that C provides. I could get it down another 10 bytes if I could have 128 bit numbers though =/

Comment: Very nice with the decimal version also. Wish I could upvote this again!

Answer (score 7):

## Ruby, *0123* chars + a bonus ([0123] vs '#')

```
f=15
0.upto(4){|n|$*[0].chars{|x|$><<"%4s "%eval(:f6ff929192279241f7ff[x.to_i+4*n]).to_i.to_s(2).tr(?0,' ').tr(?1,x)}
puts}
```

Example:

```
% ruby ./font.rb 01231231
0000  11  2222 3333  11  2222 3333  11  
0  0   1  2  2    3   1  2  2    3   1  
0  0   1    2   333   1    2   333   1  
0  0   1   2      3   1   2      3   1  
0000  111 2222 3333  111 2222 3333  111
% ruby ./font.rb 01231231102020103201301203212302230
0000  11  2222 3333  11  2222 3333  11   11  0000 2222 0000 2222 0000  11  0000 3333 2222 0000  11  3333 0000  11  2222 0000 3333 2222  11  2222 3333 0000 2222 2222 3333 0000 
0  0   1  2  2    3   1  2  2    3   1    1  0  0 2  2 0  0 2  2 0  0   1  0  0    3 2  2 0  0   1     3 0  0   1  2  2 0  0    3 2  2   1  2  2    3 0  0 2  2 2  2    3 0  0 
0  0   1    2   333   1    2   333   1    1  0  0   2  0  0   2  0  0   1  0  0  333   2  0  0   1   333 0  0   1    2  0  0  333   2    1    2   333 0  0   2    2   333 0  0 
0  0   1   2      3   1   2      3   1    1  0  0  2   0  0  2   0  0   1  0  0    3  2   0  0   1     3 0  0   1   2   0  0    3  2     1   2      3 0  0  2    2      3 0  0 
0000  111 2222 3333  111 2222 3333  111  111 0000 2222 0000 2222 0000  111 0000 3333 2222 0000  111 3333 0000  111 2222 0000 3333 2222  111 2222 3333 0000 2222 2222 3333 0000
```

## EDIT: Ruby, 87 chars

```
0.upto(4){|n|$*[0].bytes{|x|$><<"%04b0"%:f6ff929192279241f7ff[x-48+4*n].to_i(16)}
puts}
```

[image]

Comment: A creative one! Very nice. This will look fabulous in my designs. Have an upvote.

Comment: Tricky! Will take me some time to understand it.

Answer (score 5):

## Ruby

### Vertical: 116 characters

```ruby
f="f999f62227f924ff171f".chars.map{|c|c.hex.to_s(2).rjust(4).tr"01"," #"}
$<.chars{|c|i=c.to_i*5;$><<f[i,5]*$/+$/*2}
```

Sample run:

```
bash-4.2$ echo -n 321 | ruby -e 'f="f999f62227f924ff171f".chars.map{|c|c.hex.to_s(2).rjust(4).tr"01"," #"};$<.chars{|c|i=c.to_i*5;$><<f[i,5]*$/+$/*2}'
####
   #
 ###
   #
####

####
#  #
  # 
 #  
####

 ## 
  # 
  # 
  # 
 ###
```

### Horizontal: <s>150</s> 148 characters

```ruby
f="f999f62227f924ff171f".chars.map{|c|c.hex.to_s(2).rjust(4).tr"01"," #"}
o=(0..4).map{""}
$<.chars{|c|5.times{|j|o[j]<<f[c.to_i*5+j]+" "}}
$><<o*$/
```

Sample run:

```
bash-4.2$ echo -n 321 | ruby -e 'f="f999f62227f924ff171f".chars.map{|c|c.hex.to_s(2).rjust(4).tr "01"," #"};o=(0..4).map{""};$<.chars{|c|5.times{|j|o[j]<<f[c.to_i*5+j]+" "}};$><<o*$/'
#### ####  ##  
   # #  #   #  
 ###   #    #  
   #  #     #  
#### ####  ###
```

Comment: I was going to encode it like that. Don't think I can beat this is my language though!

Answer (score 4):

## Mathematica <strike>174</strike> <strike>145</strike> <strike>139</strike> <strike>118</strike> <strike>119</strike> 123 chars

Now works with input in base 10 (Integer bonus).  Earlier versions can be found in edits.

---

**Using ArrayPlot**:

With `ArrayPlot` we can directly convert the 1's and 0's to black and white squares, saving a few chars in the process.  For example, with n = 58021, which is **32022211** in base 4:

```
i = IntegerDigits; i[n, 4] /. Thread@Rule[0~Range~3, ArrayPlot /@ ((PadLeft[#, 4] & /@ i[#, 2]) & /@ (i@{89998, 62227, 89248, 81718} /. {8 -> 15}))]
```

[image: integer bonus]

---

**Explanation**

Input is program parameter, `n`.

Zero can be represented by `{{1,1,1,1},{1,0,0,1},{1,0,0,1},{1,0,0,1},{1,1,1,1}`
or by the hex counterpart `f999f`.

The expression, `f999f62227f924ff171f`, holds the information to display all the numbers {0,1,2,3}. (Note: it begins with `f999f`, which as we noted, is zero in disguise.)  Because Mathematica does not recognize this as a number, I used  `89998622278924881718` (in four integer strings) instead, broke up the number into its integer digits, and then used 15 in every place an 8 appeared.  (That allowed me to use digits instead of strings throughout.)

Comment: Your output doesn't match the input.

Comment: Can't you just transpose that for the vertical bonus?

Comment: As I understand the rules, the bonus is for the horizontal configuration.

Comment: Mr. Lister Good catch. I copied and pasted the picture of zero in the place of 1.

Comment: My bad, misread.

Comment: Pretty cool to output is as matrices. Nice one.

Comment: @Accatyyc Thanks. Btw, were you able to figure out what `89998622278924881718` stands for?

Comment: I haven't really analyzed it since I'm on a bus right now, but my initial thought was that it is a bitmap representation of the characters. Not sure about the format though!

Comment: I'll explain it in the text.

Comment: That's not bending the rules. It says clearly in the OP that '#' can be replaced by any character :)

Comment: @Accatyyc Thanks. I hadn't noticed.

Answer (score 3):

### *Mathematica*, <s>112</s> <s>107</s> 103

My take on David's method.

```
i=IntegerDigits;Grid/@i@n/.Thread[0~Range~3->("#"i[i@#/.8->15,2,4]&/@{89998,62227,89248,81718}/.0->"")]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

#### 105 with the BONUS:

(for `n = 54321`)

```
i=IntegerDigits;Grid/@n~i~4/.Thread[0~Range~3->("#"i[i@#/.8->15,2,4]&/@{89998,62227,89248,81718}/.0->"")]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Very nice indeed. So few characters with the bonus. Good work!

Answer (score 3):

### APL (<s>58</s> 57)

```
{' #'[1+5 4⍴1022367 401959 1020495 988959[1+⍎⍵]⊤⍨20⍴2]}¨⍞
```

Output:

```
0123
 ####   ##   ####  #### 
 #  #    #   #  #     # 
 #  #    #     #    ### 
 #  #    #    #       # 
 ####   ###  ####  ####
```

Answer (score 2):

## Python 2.7

### Vertical 160

```
for i in input():print['****\n*  *\n*  *\n*  *\n****',' ** \n  * \n  * \n  * \n***','****\n*  *\n  * \n *  \n****','****\n   *\n ***\n   *\n****'][int(i)]+'\n'
```

### Horizontal <strike>234</strike> 216

```
x=[['****\n*  *\n*  *\n*  *\n****',' ** \n  * \n  * \n  * \n ***','****\n*  *\n  * \n *  \n****','****\n   *\n ***\n   *\n****'][int(i)]for i in input()]
for i in range(5):print' '.join([y.split('\n')[i]for y in x])
```

Both take input as a quoted string on stdin

example:
$./pretty
"0123"

Comment: How you run this? I get errors. Python 2: "TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable", Python 3: "TypeError: 'builtin_function_or_method' object is not subscriptable".

Comment: @manatwork This is in python 2.7, I have edited the answer to make that clear.

Comment: @manatwork Also, it looks like you may have been entering the numbers without quotes around them ie: 0123. You should try entering "0123" on stdin.

Comment: Got it working now. Sorry, that quoting trick was not evident for me.

Comment: @manatwork in python versions before 3 the input() function evaluates the input as if it were a python expression. If the quotes are not there, the program tries to iterate over an integer, giving you the error you got.